# Fitness function in genetic algorithm for the travelling salesman

Tags: genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to write a genetic algorithm for the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP). For selection I'm implementing Roulette Wheel Selection: http://www.edc.ncl.ac.uk/highlight/rhjanuary2007g02.php/

It basicaly means that the probability to be selected for mating is proportional to the value of the fitness function.
The most common fitness function for TSP is the length of the route. However, the 'shorter' the route is - the better.

How can I write a fitness function that will describe the shortness of the route?
Or how can I convert the true length of each route to a probability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a cost function (the lower the better) that you want to convert to a fitness function (the higher the better).

Use the inverse. If the cost (distance) is `x` then your fitness could become `1/x`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually that is not a problem for the fitness function, but for the selection step. You should also use windowing in proportional selection so that you scale the fitness values. Otherwise the operator will exert too little selection pressure: just imagine the values 573 and 579 they're very close and thus will have about the same proportion. Typically you scale them by the current best and worst fitness.

You can take a look at the ProportionalSelector that we implemented in [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). You can even try and experiment with that software and explore different selection methods, crossovers, mutation operators, etc